# lightweight web browser with emacs-like keybindings

Tags: linux, software-rec, browser, emacs

Uzbl uses hjkl for moving around, much like vim does. I was wondering if there was a browser (text based like links, or needing X like uzbl) which would be easy for someone used to emacs key bindings?

Or if there is an emacs mode for having a buffer behave like a Links browser, but with emacs keybindings to move around...

[For linux systems, please ideally something available through AUR or a debian package or both]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [Emacs interface to w3m](http://emacs-w3m.namazu.org/). Debian and Ubuntu ship it as `w3m-el`. The [Emacs wiki has a page about it](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/emacs-w3m).

Also, [w3](http://www.gnu.org/software/w3/) is a browser entirely written in Emacs lisp, but it's fallen out of the major distributions.

Comment: In most cases, if you want "something with emacs key bindings" what you want is emacs... B-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use Firefox with the [Conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) extension.

(I know Firefox is not text-based, but Conkeror kind of makes it text-based. At least there are no menues, buttons, etc. anymore.)

Comment: Conkeror is more a standalone browser then a Firefox extension.

Answer (score 0):

`w3m` uses the VI keybindings.

[emacs-w3m](http://emacs-w3m.namazu.org/) is a clone which uses emacs keybindings.

Comment: That is not an answer to my question.

Comment: A quick google, did however lead me to this ( http://emacs-w3m.namazu.org/ ) which does, sort of.

Comment: @Seamus: Sorry, somehow mixed that up.